# Same domain links outside Vuepress application

Tags: vuejs2, vuepress

Our main product is hosted on https://ourproduct.com/
and our Vuepress based docs app is hosted on https://ourproduct.com/docs.

Now from one of our MD files we want to point to a child page of our product application i.e. https://ourproduct.com/features

we can't provide absolute URLs here as this link is environment specific.

When I use `[Explore Features] (/features)`, Vuepress adds basepath of docs app to this link and I am not able to navigate to our features page.

Any cleaner solution? Or I am missing something straight forward here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I achieved it:

- Enabled custom Vue Components in config.js using [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuepress/plugin-register-components)
- Created custom Vue component in `.vuepress/components` directory
- This component accepts href & target as prop & use those for creating a plain anchor with absolute URL by apending location.origin.
- Used it in my md files

```
<domain-relative-url href="/features">Features<domain-relative-url>
```